# Cannot svn update, An error occurred during decompression

Tags: svn, windows-8.1

I have a problem with my remote repo in svn. I am running svn version 1.8.5 on windows 8.1

When I try to do an svn update I get the error
svn: E120104: ra_serf: An error occurred during decompression

I am able to do a clean checkout.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: we are facing the same issue when using the official `svn.exe` 1.8.8 (r1568071) - but when using the `svn.exe` which ships with tortoiseSVN, which is awkwardly the same revision, it works ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was never fully resolved, I worked around this by doing a clean checkout and migrating the changes to the new working copy.

Answer (score 4):

This is not limited to Windows. I was having this issue on OS X, when trying to commit. I added the following to the client side `~/.subversion/servers`, based on [Nathan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32886583/1255289) about disabling compression:

```
[global]
http-compression = no
```

This resolved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This [wandisco forum post](http://www.wandisco.com/svnforum/forum/opensource-subversion-forums/general-setup-and-troubleshooting/linux-unix-servers/13057-e120104-ra_serf-an-error-occurred-during-decompression) will lead you in the right direction. Assuming you have access to the repo server, you need to disable compression with mod_deflate.

To resolve this error when attempting to export a large (> 4GB) repository on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, do the following:

On the server hosting the repo:

```
mv /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/deflate.load ~/backup_deflate.load
mv /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/deflate.conf ~/backup_deflate.conf
mv /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_deflate.so ~/backup_mod_deflate.so
sudo service apache2 restart
```

As described in other posts, changing the client is also a workable solution. With access to the repo server, this approach was faster to implement and required no changes by the users.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue, unfortunately it could not be solved by defining the `http-compression = no`option. After investigation, it turned out, that an option recommended by [HTML5 boilerplate Apache Compression settings](https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-apache/blob/master/src/web_performance/compression.conf) caused this issue. We had to temporary disabled the following option:

```
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddEncoding gzip              svgz
</IfModule>
```

While `AddEncoding gzip svgz` was inactive, commit of files which name included the term `svgz` was possible.

Comment: This was the only option that worked for me. See also https://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2015-07/0012.shtml

Answer (score -2):

From [Checking out with an older version of SVN on server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27104527/checking-out-with-an-older-version-of-svn-on-server) this site, this problem is caused by the HTTP client libraries.

I'm tring to install svn with old version(1.7.19) as alvas said on the previous website. Maybe the following error

> configure: error: no XML parser was found: expat or libxml 2.x required

will occur.

You can download the expat-2.1.0.tar.gz from http://sourceforge.net/projects/expat/files/

But the older version may not support SSL. Use 'http' instead of 'https'.
My environment is  AMD_64 + Ubuntu14.04 LTS.